# FetchedResultsController sectionKeyPath on different entity

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Is it possible to define a sectionKeyPath that is on a different entity?

I have a set of users which are the entities the fetchedResultsController is displaying. I would like to sort them into 2 sections, based on whether they have unread messages or not.

So I need to get the message using user.lastMessageId and then use message.viewed as the sectionKeyPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you can use an attribute of a different entity as the `sectionNameKeyPath` for an FRC, but there must be a to-one relationship from the entity underlying the FRC to the entity with the attribute in question.

You mention a `lastMessageID` attribute, which implies you are storing a unique ID to the last message.  Replace this instead with a to-one relationship `lastMessage` to the `Message` entity, and populate this with the relevant `Message` object rather than its unique ID.  You can then use `lastMessage.viewed` as your `sectionNameKeyPath`.  Note that you will also need to add a sort descriptor to sort the FRC entities by the same key.